# Swift access control for extensions defined in a Unit Test

Tags: swift

I'm trying to extend a class in the Unit Tests, giving the tests an API that is available only to the tests. This test API is not appropriate for normal use, and I don't want to expose otherwise private properties and methods in the original class.

For example, the following is a class that includes an extension in the same file. As expected, the extension here can see all properties, including the private ones, as the extension is part of the original file.

```
class DoSomething {

    private     var aPrivate:String?     = nil
    fileprivate var aFilePrivate:String? = nil
    internal    var anInternal:String?   = nil
    public      var aPublic:String?      = nil
}

extension DoSomething {
    func anExtensionInSameFile() {
        aPrivate     = "aaa"  // works (private includes extensions defined in the same file)
        aFilePrivate = "bbb"  // works
        anInternal   = "ccc"  // works
        aPublic      = "ddd"  // works
    }
}
```

Note that an external class defined in another file only has access to the `internal` and `public` properties, as expected.

```
class DoAnotherThing {

    let doSomething = DoSomething()

    func whatEver() {
        // Only internal and public variables are visible - as expected
        doSomething.anInternal = "111"
        doSomething.aPublic    = "222"
    }
}
```

My Unit Test class has an extension, intending to add an extra API that should be visible to the tests only. I need access to private properties and methods, but do NOT want to expose those properties to other classes.

Unfortunately, the extension that is defined with my tests can not see `private` or `fileprivate` properties.

```
import XCTest
@testable import navigation

extension DoSomething {
    func anExtensionForTestingOnly() {
        aPrivate     = "www"  // does not compile
        aFilePrivate = "xxx"  // does not compile
        anInternal   = "yyy"  // works
        aPublic      = "zzz"  // works
    }
}

class DoSomethingTests: XCTestCase {

    override func setUp() {
        super.setUp()
    }
    override func tearDown() {
        super.tearDown()
    }

    func testAnything() {
        let doSomething = DoSomething()

        doSomething.anExtensionForTestingOnly() // only available from the tests

        // only has visibility to internal and public properties
        doSomething.anInternal = "333"
        doSomething.aPublic    = "444"
    }
}
```

I don't think Swift has an Access Control that will allow access to extensions, which is what I believe I need to do this.

Comment: This is by design. Importing an a module gives you access to public symbols, using @testable imports extends the access to internal symbols. You should structure your api in a way that doesn't require you to access private or change some of the private fields to  be internal